# How to run Digital ocean droplet with appwrite, ghost cms AND Sveltekit

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean, sveltekit, ghost-blog, appwrite

So I am developing a simple web-app and site and locally I have appwrite as well as sveltekit running.

On digital ocean i made a droplet using the appwrite 1 click install then I added a domain. The domain now defaults to appwrite of course so now I would like to do a few things:

1. Set it up so that Appwrite is running on subdomain, like app-api.domain.com versus the default domain.com
2. Add Ghost CMS to this droplet and set to blog-api.domain.com
3. Add my Sveltekit app as default to be accessed by domain.com

I have basic linux experience from way back in the day and I am currently binging linux server youtube videos but they are not digital ocean specific. So I am not sure where linux stores files for default webserver stuff like how folder structure in xampp would be...

I can run terminal from the digital ocean side and so i am trying to learn and explore there too.

Please help!

So I tried all the options on the digital ocean side and ended up by the terminal which I am still learning as well as how Appwrite is set up there.
I am also opening digital ocean FAQ hunting for solutions as well as spend a few hours googling the issue.
Also went to the market place to see if the installs there had some kind of "add install to droplet" feature.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you'll need a reverse proxy. Since a server can only serve one application on a particular port, you can't have all 3 apps listening on port 443 (HTTPS). This is where a reverse proxy helps. The reverse proxy can listen on port 443 and then direct traffic to whichever app (listening on some non-standard port) depending on the hostname requested.

I don't like to deal with reverse proxies and prefer an easy setup, so I use Nginx Proxy Manager (NPM) as my reverse proxy. You can refer to [this](https://medium.com/@stnguyen90/how-to-run-appwrite-behind-nginx-19348ed34243) if you also want to use NPM.

Comment: tank you for this! Will look into it!